# What does SO refer to?

Tags: idioms, so

> Because the ocean basins really are short-lived features on geologic
>   times scale, reconstruction the world’s geography by backtracking
>   along the hot-spot trail works only for the last 5 percent or **so** of
>   geologic time.

Comment: "or so"  - imprecise but fairly close to correct; in this case, it means "about 5 percent of geologic time"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Or so** is an idiom that means "approximately".](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/or-so)  So the author is saying that this method works for approximately five percent of geologic time.

You see this idiom used a lot with numbers where the exact number is unknown or unimportant.  For example,

> [He had asked a dozen or so people.  ...  At half past seven or so there would begin the buffet dinner...](https://books.google.com/books?id=VDC0IDQf0DEC&pg=PT286&dq=%22or%20so%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUkeLN7cjNAhUFaz4KHe14BKc4KBDoAQg2MAU#v=onepage&q=%22or%20so%22&f=false)
>
> [Louie had seen a few tarantulas during his years in the business, although he couldn't recall one in the past ten years or so.](https://books.google.com/books?id=SpLACAAAQBAJ&pg=PT104&dq=%22or%20so%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnxPih7cjNAhWBXD4KHS7uAawQ6AEIRjAH#v=onepage&q=%22or%20so%22&f=false)
>
> [Digital photography has been in use for three decades or so...](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ow6QAgAAQBAJ&pg=PR17&dq=%22or%20so%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUns_d7cjNAhUCcz4KHRM0DJ44UBDoAQhDMAk#v=onepage&q=%22or%20so%22&f=false)